# Session vs Instance vs Database in Oracle NLS Settings

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Why in Oracle there are **three** logical **distinct** views for **N**ational **L**anguage **S**upport ?

I can understand the need for distinguishing between session and database - to allow for client custom settings.

What about Session versus Instance ?

I ran a query to compare the values between them all, and here are the results (I noticed NLS_DATABASE_SETTINGS has more parameters all the parameters the others have plus some more, hence I am doing an outer join with it as my starting point):

```
SELECT
   db.parameter as parameter,
   db.value as database_value,
   s.value as session_value,
   i.value as instance_value
FROM
   nls_database_parameters db
LEFT JOIN 
   nls_session_parameters s
ON s.parameter = db.parameter
LEFT JOIN 
   nls_instance_parameters i
ON i.parameter = db.parameter
ORDER BY parameter
```

[image]

I am trying to dig deep and solve an issue of my pl/sql developer client, alone, not being able to display Hebrew characters. All the others in the company are.

**Update**: the issue of display characters in Hebrew (which is not the question here) was solved, following the solution I posted [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637449/pl-sql-developer-displays-does-not-display-hebrew-characters-properly).

Answer (score 6):

Nice question, I didn't know the difference between them till I did some research.
Have look at [National-Language-Support](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/oracle/article.php/3485216/The-Globalization-of-Language-in-Oracle---National-Language-Support.htm)

> NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
>
> When you create your database, you tell it how you are going to handle
> or not handle globalization of the database. The
> NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS view will display what these settings were at
> database creation time. These are fixed at the database level and
> cannot be changed. The good thing is that while they do set up some of
> your options down the road with regard to having your database talk
> globally, they are only used when check constraints are enforced in
> the database. Therefore, you will not really need to worry about what
> these settings are after database creation time.
>
> NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS
>
> As you know, you can change a variety of parameters for your instance
> through either the INIT.ORA file or the SPFILE. The
> NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS view will display those settings that are set
> at the instance level.
>
> NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS
>
> In addition, you have the ability to set each individual session's
> globalization parameters and the NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS view will show
> you what the current settings are. This view is specific to the
> session querying from it.

Comment: @PatrickHofman because each one has its own 'work' as described above, NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS when the database is created , as for NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS will show you the setting of individual setting , in my answer I covered most part. if he read the full article he will understand many things .

Comment: First things first: through others questions I myself had learned lots as well :-)

Comment: Patrick, Moudiz is right, it does add to the answer. I think the question is ultimately about the difference between an instance and a session in Oracle DBs. But this definitely adds useful info.