# Sql server linked server to Oracle return ??? instead of chars

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, linked-server, openquery

I am using Oracle 11g and Sql Server 2008 R2
In the sql Server i have a linked server connected to the Oracle machine.
In the Sql Server I am using openquery to select from a table in the Oracle.
Whenever there are char columns in the Oracle  i get all data like ???????
I try to modify the collation in the Linked Server properties windows - still get the same ??????

**How can i resolve this issue?**

here some more details about the configuration:

**Details from Oracle nls parameters :**

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN

NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,

NLS_CHARACTERSET    IW8ISO8859P8

NLS_SORT    BINARY

NLS_COMP    BINARY

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

**the linked server has this options :**

```
'collation compatible', 'false'

'data access','true'

'dist', 'false'

'pub', 'false'

'rpc', 'false'

'rpc out', 'false'

'sub', 'false'

'connect timeout', '0'

'collation name', 'Hebrew_100_CI_AS'

'lazy schema validation', 'false'

'query timeout', '0'

'use remote collation', 'true'

'remote proc transaction promotion', 'true'
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be due to mismatch between **NLS parameters** . Your Oracle `NLS_LANG = 'AMERICAN'` where as in sql server it shows something like `collation name = 'Hebrew_100_CI_AS'`. Try setting both same.

ref: [PL/SQL Developer displays does not display Hebrew characters properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25637449/pl-sql-developer-displays-does-not-display-hebrew-characters-properly)